# Creating a environement variable inside a virtual environment?

Tags: python

How do I create an environement variable to save my secret information inside a virtual enviroenment. I am using venv module in the standard library. Can anyone give me the steps?
I tried editing the bash_profile file and adding a variable, but it is not accessible inside a venv!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$HOME/.bash_profile` is not sourced into the `activate` script of the venv. You have to add your `export SECRETVAR="secretvalue"` to the end of the `activate` script instead.